# Однокоренные слова или формы одного слова?

Tags: словообразование

***Уходить и уходящий***, ***писать и написать*** - это формы слова или однокоренные слова?

Привожу фрагмент параграфа из учебника Гольцовой Н.Г.Это образец выполнения одного из упражнений.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну форму, ну и дальше что?! Как иначе-то ей написать? "В невесомости вода принимает форму шара". Шар - форма воды? Вот странно, что она противопоставляет одно другому... А ккак там вообще понятие "формы слова" вводится?

Comment: А чем "записать" - тогда отличается? Или "подписать"? Тоже форма?

Comment: В том-то и дело...

Comment: Ссылка на параграф учебника: http://www.xn--24-6kct3an.xn--p1ai/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_10-11_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81_%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/15.html

Comment: ну это вообще - ниже плинтуса. Она даже не поясняет ***чем словообразование отличается   от формообразования***. Понимай как хочешь. Это хуже, чем рассказывать слепому о том, что такое радуга. Отсюда и заморочки. Будь моя воля, я такие учебники сжигал бы на костре вместе с авторами. А что делать учителям - не знаю. Могу только посочувствовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...***писать*** и ***написать***  ―  это формы слова или однокоренные
>   слова?

Вот что пишет по этому вопросу *Л.Л. Буланин* в  пособии для учителей *"Трудные вопросы морфологии" (М., 1976)*:

> Отношения между членами видовых пар оцениваются трояко.
>
> Во-первых, члены видовых пар типа ***решить ―  решать*** (образование
>   глаголов несов. вида) и ***делать ―  сделать*** (образование глаголов
>   сов. вида) признаются формами одного и того же слова (см. *Виноградов
>   В.В. "Русский язык", М., 1972, с. 395;* см. также *Тихонов А.Н. "Члены
>   видовых корреляций ―   грамматические формы одного слова"  ― 
>   "Филологические науки", 1965, № 2*).
>
> Во-вторых, формами слова признаются только те видовые пары, в которых
>   глагол несов. вида образован от глагола сов. вида (см. *Маслов Ю.С.
>   "Морфология глагольного вида…", М. ― Л., 1963*).

Так, у Маслова:

*…соответствующий глагол изменяется (спрягается) по видам в принципе так же, как он   изменяется (спрягается) по временам, наклонениям, лицам и числам.*

> В-третьих, словоизменительные отношения между членами между членами
>   любых видовых пар вообще отрицаются, и они признаются разными
>   лексическими единицами.

Этой третьей точки зрения и придерживается школьная грамматика (используется характерное выражение: глаголы  "бывают" совершенного или несовершенного вида), относя вид **не к переменным, а к постоянным признакам глагола**.

Т, е. по поводу пары глаголов ***писать ― написать*** можно сказать, что хотя в ней приставка, образующая глагол сов. вида, и чистовидовая (не изменяет лексического значения глагола), глаголы эти по школьной грамматике **однокоренные**.

.

**Екатерина Каштанова:**

> Привожу фрагмент параграфа из учебника Гольцовой Н.Г. ...

Ну, что тут скажешь? Если называть ***на-*** в глаголе ***написать*** не *слово-*, а *формообразующим* аффиксом, то тогда, к примеру,  при морфологическом разборе формы ***написала***   надо было бы не забывать о её происхождении и вести разбор примерно так:

*Форма в предложении  —  **написала**. Нач. форма  —  **писать**.*

Да и указание о виде глагола помещать надо было бы **не в постоянные**, а **в переменные** признаки. Но ведь этого-то  Гольцова с соавторами учебника не делает...

Да, в лингвистике существует мнение, что если две смежные единицы языка различаются только грамматическим значением, то это не отдельные слова, а формы одного и того же слова (см. выше в моём ответе ссылку на работы Виноградова и Тихонова). *"В то же время многие лингвисты (**и тем более учителя**) не согласны с тем, что слова, например, **петь** и **спеть** — формы одного слова" (Успенский М.Б. "Задачи по русскому языку. Поиск и анализ трудных решений", М., 2012)*.

Ни в одном из других школьных учебников, кроме как у Гольцовой, я с возможностью называния ***на-***  в *написать* **формообразующей** приставкой не сталкивался.

.

> ***Уходить*** и ***уходящий*** ― это формы слова или однокоренные слова?

На этот вопрос, думаю, нельзя ответить однозначно. Почему?

Как сказано у [**Литневской**](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part1.htm#1),

> ...по русскому языку сегодня в среднем звене (5–9 классы) существует
>   три официальных альтернативных учебных комплекса, имеющих гриф
>   Минобразования, рекомендованных им и рассылаемых в школьные
>   библиотеки… Необходимо также иметь в виду возможность преподавания в
>   ряде школ по альтернативным и экспериментальным учебным программам,
>   которые представляют значительно видоизмененный курс русского языка.

По поводу причастий…  В разных пособиях по-разному квалифицируют причастия: в одних пособиях они рассматриваются как самостоятельная часть речи (с словообразовательным суффиксом), в других ―  как глагольная форма (с формообразовательным суффиксом).

Вот что пишет автор ряда школьных и вузовских учебников *Вера Васильевна Бабайцева ("Анализ слова и предложения", М., 2014)*:

> Каков статус суффиксов причастий и деепричастий? Какие они:
>   **словообразовательные** или **формообразовательные?**
>
> **Ответ на этот вопрос зависит от квалификации, от частеречной принадлежности 
>   причастий и деепричастий.** Как известно, есть два
>   мнения: одни учёные считают причастия и деепричастия формами глагола,
>   другие ― самостоятельными частями речи.
>
> **Если**  причастия и деепричастия трактуются как формы глагола, то
>   суффиксы причастий и деепричастий  ― формообразовательные.
>
> **Если** же причастия и деепричастия рассматриваются как самостоятельные
>   части речи, то суффиксы  ― словообразовательные.

И потому ответ на вопрос *"**Уходить** и **уходящий** ― это формы слова или однокоренные слова?"* целиком и полностью зависит от того, каким учебным пособием пользоваться.

Comment: Т, е. по поводу пары глаголов писать ― написать можно сказать, что хотя в ней приставка, образующая глагол ***несов***. вида.  У вас опечатка. Приставка ***на*** образует совершенный вид.

Comment: _**несов**_ ? === Спасибо, Серж!

Answer (score 2):

По существующей модели грамматики это разные слова. Формами слова признаются варианты, возникающие при изменении по падежам при склонении и лицам и числам при спряжении. Даже с изменением по числам существительного уже не все однозначно, есть основания считать это разными словами.

Так что глаголы разного вида, тем более разные части речи, никак не могут считаться формами одного слова.

Comment: Проблема в том, что суффиксы причастий считаются не словообразующими, а формообразующими. И причастие - это форма глагола, по мнению многих лингвистов.

Comment: А о приставке "на" в учебнике Гольцовой 10 кл.сказано, что в данном случае она образует форму (?) совершенного вида глагола "писать". Для меня это тоже явилось неожиданностью, почему и возник вопрос.

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова, Да суффиксы причастий - формообразущие. Но это само по себе ничего не значит.  Мало ли какой суффикс у слова? Вот по поводу мнения "причастие - форма глагола", это да. Серьезно переворачивает всю модель грамматики. Но тут надо разбираться, соглашаемся ли мы в рамках школьной программы с этими авторами. А если и соглашаемся, то о какой форме" вообще идет речь. Сильно сомневаюсь, что само понятие "формы" при этом останется нетронутым. По поводу Гольцова. Да, парные в видовом отношении глаголы частенько называют "формами". Но это не значит, что это ***формы одного слова***

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ исправлен**

Уходить и уходящий ― формы одного глагола (инфинитив и причастие);

писать и написать ― формы глагола, **если следовать определению формообразующей приставки.**

Из учебника для педвузов, 2009 год:**Система глагольных форм.** Глагольные формы делятся на личные/спрягаемые формы и неличные/неспрягаемые формы. К неспрягаемым формам относятся инфинитив, причастие и деепричастие.

Глаголы совершенного и несовершенного вида - это разные глаголы (не разные формы глагола), **но, оказывается, не всегда**.

В одном случае наличие приставки **может менять** не только вид (грамматику) глагола, но и его лексическое значение (например, придавать определенную направленность). Если лексическое значение не меняется, то это, по определению,  **формообразующая** приставка. **(Если, конечно, следовать этому определению).**

Примечание. У меня есть книга Гольцевой (2007), но там про видовые формы ничего не сказано.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, стр.45 учебника (у меня 2008 год) и табличку с этой страницы, которую я добавила в вопрос. Надо бы разобраться до конца и определиться. Спасибо!

Comment: _Sibylla: Наличие приставки **меняет** не только вид (грамматику) глагола, но и его **лексическое значение**..._ ===  Нет, лексическое значение  приставка не всегда меняет: при присоединении к  _**писать**_ приставки _**на-**_ изменяется **только** вид глагола.

Comment: Коллеги, тут ещё одна проблема в связи с этим вырисовывается: в основу слова формообразующие суффиксы не входят. Тогда основа слова "уходящий" -  уход-, что ли?

Comment: Точно, есть такая тема, у меня на стр.46: Формообразующие аффиксы: писать - написать, приставка НА образует форму совершенного вида.

Comment: Я думаю, что в частном случае возможна такая позиция: если аффикс не меняет лексическое значение слова, то он является формообразующим.  В словаре  для глагола обычно в этом случае сразу указывается видовая форма: ПИСАТЬ, пишу, пишешь; пишущий; писанный; -сан, -а, -о; нсв. 1. (св. написать).

Answer (score 1):

Формами одного слова  можно считать только глаголы разного вида, образующие видовую пару, а это не всегда бывает. Писать-написать-как раз видовая пара.Насчёт совершенного-несовершенного вида почитайте здесь: http://rusgram.narod.ru/1384-1407.html

§ 1394. В образовании видовой пары способом перфективации принимают участие следующие префиксы: вз- (потеть - вспотеть), воз- (мужать- возмужать), вы- (купать - выкупать), за- (вербовать - завербовать), из- (пугать - испугать), на- (писать - написать), о- (слабеть - ослабеть),об- (лицевать - облицевать), от- (редактировать - отредактировать), по- (белеть - побелеть), под- (считать - подсчитать), при- (готовить -приготовить), про- (сигнализировать - просигнализировать), раз- (будить - разбудить), с- (делать - сделать), у- (топить - утопить).

У Гольцовой и Шамшина причастие и деепричастие - формы глагола. Откройте параграф 17"Формообразование".

Comment: Людмила, каким определением "видовой пары" тут можно воспользоваться. Написать - помимо того, что это совершенный вид еще и законченное (результативное) действие. Можно писать писать - но не написать. Закончить писание, но не завершить. Значит, условие семантической эквивалентности уже не выполнено. Нужно другое определение. А его его нет. На этом "горят" все рассуждения о видовой паре как о формообразующем элементе.

Comment: Не вижу разницы значений, только непредельность - предельность.Другое дело, что одни ученые ( Виноградов) считают члены любой видовой пары формами одного глагола( основание- семантич. критерий: тождество лексических значений членов видовой пары считается показателем того, что они являются формами одного глагола. Другие ученые считают глаголы, входящие в пары типа делать - сделать, разными глаголами, а глаголы в парах типа переписать - переписывать - формами одного глагола (. Маслов,  Бондарко); основание - регулярность образования видовых пар в результате процесса имперфективации.

Comment: Если Гольцова считает пару формами одного слова, зачем с ней спорить? По её же учебнику занимаются.Нужно принять это и выполнить упражнение в соответствии с её представлениями. Она учёный, имеет право

Comment: Ну еще спроть с ней. ))) Пусть только объяснит, каким критерием она пользуется.

Comment: А что вы не видите разницу -  сие странно. Я писал. Написал или не написал  - неизвестно. Я написал - это точно что-то совершил, довел до конца. А не просто "закончил". Меня убивает, что этого не понимают.  Любая "видовая пара" этим страдает, может за единичными исключениями. Неужели вас никто о подобном не спрашивал?    Можно по-другому. "Я не писал" (не приступал). "Я не написал" (не закончил). Разница уже разительная.

Comment: Напишите ей, пусть объяснит. Я однажды влезла в дискуссию с учёным - не рада была. Они на этих учебниках деньги делают, а мы лезем со своими вопросами. Хоть кто-нибудь из работающих учителей спросил у Лопатина и Зализняка, почему в учебниках ничего не изменилось после их отмены списков исключений? Им наплевать, кто как будет писать, лишь бы их правоту поддержали. А учат по-прежнему, учителя и не знают об этой отмене.